# Find upper and/or lower bounds for the least prime $p$ such that $p^n + k$ is the product of $n$ distinct primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, searching

Well, first of all, happy new year to everyone.

I am trying to solve the following problem: "Let $k$ be a fixed natural number.  Find the least prime $p$ such that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $p^n + k$ is the product of $n$ distinct primes."  As a related problem, suppose that $k,n$ are both fixed and find the least prime $p$ for which $p^k+n$ is the product of $n$ distinct primes.

Now, let's say I have found the least prime $p$ for a specific value of $n$ and $k$. Can we find a lower and/or upper bound for the problem when we want to look for the $n+1$ case or in general for the $n+a$ case?

I've no idea how to proceed or start in this problem.

---

As an example, when [$k=2$](https://oeis.org/A358656) we have the following solutions:

$$(p,n)\in{(3,1),(2,2),(7,3),(71,4),(241,5),(83,6),(157,7),\dots}\tag1$$

And when $k=4$ we have the following solutions:

$$(p,n)\in{(3,1),(19,2),(11,3),(29,4),(131,5),(983,6),(353,7),\dots}\tag2$$

Comment: Not sure what's given here.  Are you saying, "for fixed natural numbers $n,k$ let $F(n,k)$ denote the least prime $p$ such that..."  or are not fixing both $n,k$?

Comment: In any case, I would imagine it's very, very difficult to find such a prime in general.  In particular, I can't imagine why knowing $F(n,k)$ would help with $F(n+1,k)$.  Do you have some reason to imagine that the problem is tractable?

Comment: @lulu No, $k$ is fixed and $n\in\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots\right\}$. I am now writing some code and running it for hours/days looking for a specific solution for a given value of $n$ and I am trying to narrow the search down to increase search speed. Maybe there is no shortcut, but that is obviously also possible.

Comment: So...$k$ alone is fixed and then we seek a pair $(p,n)$ such that $p$ is minimal and $p,k,n$ satisfy the given property?  Honestly, that's not at all clear from what you wrote.  In any case, I'd be very surprised to see a method better than brute force.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry, I am not a native English speaker. Feel free to edit.